# Can't access table while inserting data

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

When I add a million rows to one table in the database I am unable to access a different table while the insertion is still in progress. Is it possible to get access in this time?
I use BEGIN; and COMMIT; to speed up the process a little bit but it still takes 20 - 30 seconds.

Comment: Uh, starting a transaction will _not_ speed things up.  In all RDBMSs, transactions will require a larger portion of system resources (how much depends on different things).  Most on-disk systems are at least kind enough to not lock _other_ tables, although inserting a million rows in a transaction may cause it to lock **that** entire table.

Answer (score 2):

No.

sqlite locks the entire database when an exclusive transaction is ongoing.

If you need concurrency, move the other table to another database. Or switch to another database engine that has been designed to support concurrent access better.

Comment: Could you recommend a specific database engine?